# How to export c# function so it can be called from unmanaged environment?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how can I export a function so I can use it in other programming language?

I want to use the dll functions in unmanaged programming language.

What can I do?

Comment: you well still need `.NET framework` to run c#.

Comment: Ofc I need .net framework so I can run c# to create the code but I need to know how to export the functions like c++ does

Comment: In short - you need to initialize the .NET framework and then call it using reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run [regasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28VS.80%29.aspx) with the `/tlb` command against your .NET assembly and then reference the output type library (tlb) from C++.

I've done this many times before and it can be a pain, especially when you go to deploy it.  I recommend using the `/codebase` switch, which tells the registry where to find your .NET assembly when its classes are instantiated in a COM context.  That makes it easy to find in the registry and tweek it as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Two articles that may be of use... it sounds rather painful:

- [An Overview of Managed/Unmanaged Code Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx)
- [Exposing .NET Framework Components to COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx)